# How to transform multi-column dataframes to three-column dataframes in pandas more efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

This function gets the job done, but it is slow.
I'm sure you can think of a more efficient way, maybe with some built-in pandas functions?

```
def getUtilizationForDatabase(self, df):
    result = pd.DataFrame(columns={"Wertstrom", "MaGr", "Auslastung"})
    for i in range(len(df)):
        for f in range(1, len(df.columns)):
            entry = pd.DataFrame({"Wertstrom": df.loc[i, "Wertstrom"], "MaGr": df.columns[f], "Auslastung": df.iloc[i, f]}, index=[0])
            result = pd.concat([result, entry], ignore_index=True, sort=True)
    return result
```

Input:

| Wertstrom | M100 | M200 | M300 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 | 1.2 | 3.3 | ... |
| 2 | 2.5 | 2.2 | 3.1 | ... |

Output:

| Wertstrom | MaGr | Auslastung |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M100 | 2.5 |
| 1 | M200 | 1.2 |
| 1 | M300 | 3.3 |
| 2 | M100 | 2.5 |
| 2 | M200 | 2.2 |
| 3 | M300 | 3.1 |

The original input-table is 60x120. I do need the data in a relational database, this is why i want to transform the data in less columns and query instead.

Comment: you could use `melt` to move rows to columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df.melt(d_vars=["Wertstrom"], 
        var_name="MaGr", 
        value_name="Auslastung")
```

In older version on pandas(<0.20):

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Wertstrom"], 
            var_name="MaGr", 
            value_name="Auslastung")
```

Answer (score 0):

Melting:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

```
df.melt(d_vars=["Wertstrom"], 
    var_name="MaGr", 
    value_name="Auslastung")
```